# Convert a radio button to a ON/OFF toggle Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to convert a radio button to a bootstrap ON/OFF toggle.  I know how to do it for a checkbox:

```
<input checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
```

I tried it for a radio button by replacing the type of checkbox with radio, instead I got a normal radio button.

What i mean by ON/OFF toggle is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[bootstrap switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)**  :

Include the dependencies: jQuery, Bootstrap and Bootstrap Switch CSS + Javascript.

```
[...]
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
[...]
```

Add your checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
Initialize Bootstrap Switch.
```

**jquery**

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

Enjoy.

You can use the plugin for Turn checkboxes and radio buttons in toggle switches

Comment: yes you can do this look at this example http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html at the end onf the page